# Change month name to month number in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, ssis, etl

I have a source file which has 50 columns. One of the columns is `TransDateTime` and the value in it is of format `22-MAY-2017 02:31:15.00`. Now before loading this source file to final destination table i want it to be converted to the format `22-05-2017 02:31:15.00` so that i can use the data type `datetime` for that column.

I have seen ways to convert month name to month number if the column just contains the month value like below.

- http://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/11/ssis-how-to-convert-month-name-into.html

I am not sure how to work around this scenario in my case. Any solutions?

Comment: Are you using SSIS to load the data (as in the example)? Or are you looking for a way through a query?

Comment: I am using ssis data flow task

Comment: I would do this: push the source data into a staging table, raw, using SSIS. Then write a query to parse the date for everything between the two dashes (using CHARINDEX probably) and replace with numeric equivalent, and then reformat the date. Run that as an Execute SQL task. Finally, push data from the staging table into the destination.

Answer (score 2):

Well one solution would be to REPLACE.   Simply replace "MAY" with "05" and you get the desired outcome from your sample input.

Nest 12 REPLACE functions in one expression and you will handle every possible scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Use a script component. Convert the input column to your desired format like this in `C#`:

```
DateTime.Parse("22-MAY-2017 02:31:15.00").ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff");
```

For example, if your input column is MyDate and Out put column is OutPutCol then:

```
OutPutCol = DateTime.Parse(Row.MyDate).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff");
```

You can [check the code here](http://rextester.com/live/ZBUW56310).

Answer (score 0):

If your destination column datatype is `datetime`, so you are not looking to reformat your date string. but you are looking to convert this string into date value.

You can add a `Script COmponent` in the dataflow task, with an output column of type `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` and mark `TransDateTime` Column as input. and use the following code: *(i used VB.NET)*

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Output0Buffer)  

    Row.OutDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.TransDateTime,"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff",New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"))  

End Sub
```

If your destination column is of type string then you have to follow the same steps but the output column should be of type `DT_STR` and you have to use the following code:

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Output0Buffer)  

    Row.OutDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.TransDateTime,"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff",New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff")  

End Sub
```